# Syntax Error: Unexpected '===' (T_IS_IDENTICAL), expecting ',' or ')'

Tags: php

The error I'm getting is:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '===' (T_IS_IDENTICAL), expecting ',' or ')' in /home/site/public_html/lp-928.php on line 2`

The PHP code

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['one']) && isset($_GET['two']) && !isset($_GET['one'] === '{one}') && !isset($_GET['two'] === '{two}') ) {
    $value = "12";
}else{
    $value = "3";
}?>
```

What I'm trying to do is pass a value of `12` if the get variable `one` or `two` is in present and I'm also trying to pass the value `12` if the strings `{one}` and `{two}` are NOT present.   Where did I go wrong?

Comment: _“Where did I go wrong?”_ – in using `isset` for actual value comparison, which is not its job.

Comment: @CBroe what do you suggest? I'm pretty new to PHP

Comment: PHP interpereter told you everything: you should not use compare statement in isset() function, separate them into different conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['one']) && isset($_GET['two']) && ($_GET['one'] === '{one}') && ($_GET['two'] === '{two}') ) {
    $value = "12";
}else{
    $value = "3";
}?>
```

Comment: will this work if `{one}` and `{two}` are not present?

Comment: @JoeBobby It won't behave in the same way then. The if statement will run if they just example, but if you remove the comparisons, then the text can be anything.

Comment: @DaveChen how would I get this to work since I have to specifically check to make sure `{one}` and `{two}` are not present before setting the value?

Comment: @JoeBobby If `{one}` and `{two}` are **not** present? Do you mean `$_GET['one']` is **not** equal to `{one}`? In that case, change `===` to `!==` within the code.

Comment: @DaveChen what I mean is if {one} is anywhere in the URL, I want the value `3` to be set.. is that the same thing as what you mentioned above?

Comment: This code only answer doesn't explain the cause of the issue for future users.