# Checking for These 3 Conditions

Tags: php

I'm trying to check my URL for 3 conditions before assigning a value.

if my URL is `http://example.com/page.php` I want to make sure that the url:

has the `one` or `two` get variable in the url:

`http://example.com/page.php?one=`or `http://example.com/page.php?two=`

does **NOT** have `{one}`  or `{two}` in the string:

`http://example.com/page.php?one={one}` or `http://example.com/page.php?two={two}`

and is not directly to my page **without** the get variables

`http://example.com/page.php`

If these 3 conditions are met I want to assign the value of `12`.

I asked before how to do this a specific way, but I was told what I was doing was wrong so I'm trying to do this the correct way so there are no php warnings/notices

here is what I'm using now that works only for checking if the get variables are in the url:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['one']) && isset($_GET['two'])) {
    $value = "12";
}else{
    $value = "3";
}?>
```

What would be the correct way to check my URL for all that I want above before setting a value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax Error: Unexpected '===' (T\_IS\_IDENTICAL), expecting ',' or ')'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996303/syntax-error-unexpected-t-is-identical-expecting-or)

Comment: *"I asked before how to do this a specific way..."* - Ask the people who have already given you answers. Yes, you have asked this, but this is a duplicate question.

Comment: You should be using `||` not `&&` based on your description. Also, you aren't checking if `{one}` or `{two}` are there

Comment: @Fred-ii- my other thread where i was told i was doing it incorrectly..

Comment: [This answer given](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24996333/) seemed to be going somewhere, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @asimes I know because I don't know how to check if `{one}` or `{two}` are there.. in my other thread I was told what I was doing was incorrect so instead of asking for a specific way to do it since im new to php, I'm asking for the best way to check for the rest

Comment: @asimes could you help me understand why i shoudl be using `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: @JoeBobby, I tried to include an explanation about `||` and `&&` in an answer below

Comment: You should rewrite your original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$firstConditionMet = false;
$secondConditionMet = false;
$thirdConditionMet = false;

if(isset($_GET['one']) || isset($_GET['two'])) {
    $firstConditionMet = true;
}

if($_GET['one'] != "{one}" && $_GET['two']!="{two}") {
    $secondConditionMet = true;
}

$thirdConditionMet = $firstConditionMet;

if($firstConditionMet && $secondConditionMet && $thirdConditionMet) {
    $value = "12";
}else{
    $value = "3";
}

?>
```